# Moving a Piaggio Ape from Germany to Spain

Tags: germany, transportation, spain, road-trips

I am planning to move a Piaggio Ape (pictured below) from Southern Germany (Munich Area) to Northern Spain (Galicia) for a road trip through Northern Spain & Portugal next summer. I don't want to drive the car there as it is not designed for long-distance travel. Therefore I am looking for alternative ways to get the car to Spain.

[image: Green Piaggio Ape]

I will most probably leave the Ape in Spain for a friend to have it so I am not concerned with returning it to Germany, but only with getting it to Spain.

What are some viable options for this task? Has someboy else performed a similar move (e.g. a heavy motorcycle from Central Europe to Spain)?

Comment: Just to be clear: You don't want to drive it there?

Comment: @drat I can see why someone might not want to go that far in such a vehicle.
OP, do you have access to any larger vehicles, and/or are you in posession of a suitable liscence for a vehicle that can tow?

Comment: @CMaster Of course, just want to clarify that the OP that he is looking for a shipping arrangement and not a route.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear since I don't understand if you want to ship it or to drive it.

Comment: Correct, I don't want to drive the car there as it is not designed for long-distance travel.

Comment: I think we understood that you don't want to drive the car itself, but is the obvious solution to simply tow it on a trailer or put it in the back of a small lorry an option? Or are you looking for a shipping agent able to transport it for you?